# PHP receiving Json

Tags: php, ajax, json, knockout.js

I'm using knockout and I'm trying to send information to PHP, using firebug to check Network -> Headers I have this:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/loyalty/welcome/json/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:85
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/loyalty/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.46 Safari/535.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
{"friends":[{"name":"name","isOnTwitter":false},{"name":"name","isOnTwitter":false}]}
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 15 Feb 2012 11:01:23 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.8
```

The generated JSON is: `{"friends":[{"name":"name","isOnTwitter":false},{"name":"name","isOnTwitter":false}]}` and I have no idea how to get those values.

Here is the Ajax call:

```
save: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/loyalty/welcome/json/",
            type: "post",
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

On my CodeIgniter method I have tried to receive it with `$this->input->post('friends')` and whatever else I could think of and no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the Javascript to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost/loyalty/welcome/json/",
    type: "post",
    data: {payload:ko.toJSON(this)},
    success: function (result) {
            t.value = result;
    }
});
```

Then, in PHP, you can access the JSON via:

```
<?php json_decode($_POST["payload"]); ?>
```

Comment: have idea why that removed line was the problem?

Comment: If you don't pass the `data` parameter as an object but as a string, jQuery assumes that you URL-encoded it already, which you hadn't. However, for PHP to read the data, it has to be URL-encoded with a variable name. Writing `data: {payload:ko.toJSON(this)}` told jQuery to URL-encode the JSON automatically and put it in the `payload` variable.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. For PHP to read the data, you have to use the MIME type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. jQuery uses this by default. Specifying `contentType: "application/json"` overrode that.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
data: ko.toJSON(this),
```

to

```
data: {mydata : ko.toJSON(this) },
```

In your file which opens up while you post on http://localhost/loyalty/welcome/json/

Read it as:

```
$myObj = json_decode($_POST['mydata']);
```

and then you can access your values as:

```
echo $myObj['friends'][0]['name']; or echo $myObj['friends'][0]['isOnTwitter'];
```

which will output `name` or `true/false` as your json code reads.

**EDIT**

This thread should help you -> [Jquery - How to make $.post() use contentType=application/json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845459/jquery-how-to-make-post-use-contenttype-application-json)

Comment: it returns me bool(false) using CodeIgniter, using $_POST[] it returns me "undefined variable: mydata"

Comment: did you make the changes as I suggested in the starting part of my answer?

Comment: yes...and here is the new JSON: mydata={"friends":[{"name":"JoÃ£o","isOnTwitter":false}]} and my php is exactly like yours

Comment: correct and then as my answer says, you need to decode the json and access it using a `foreach` or `for loop` or by directly referring to arrays as suits best to you.

Comment: right...but the problem is that in this line: $myObj = json_decode($_POST['mydata']); I already get a error "undefined index mydata"

Comment: ah yah, I have edited my answer, please refer to the javascript part again, this should solve your problem.

Comment: JSON: mydata=%7B%22friends%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Jo%C3%A3o%22%2C%22isOnTwitter%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%7D but same error =/ can you continue on chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7735/discussion-between-gerep-and-linuxeasy)

Answer (score 1):

As the Content-Type is "application/json" and NOT "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" the $_POST array will be empty.

So, in order to access the JSON payload in a POST request, you have to do this:

```
$json_data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);    
echo($json_data['param1']);
echo($json_data['param2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP to get JSON objects you need to use `json_decode()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php