# $.ajaxSetup does not set content type for Get requests

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, content-type, pagemethods

#### Code 1

```
$.ajax({url:"1.aspx/HelloWorld",type:"GET",dataType:"json",contentType:"application/json"});
```

[image: Request Response for Code1]

#### Code 2

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   contentType: "application/json",
   dataType: "json"
});

$.get("1.aspx/HelloWorld","",$.noop,"json");
```

[image: Request Response for Code 2]

Code1 effectively sets both the `content-type` and `datatype`
Code2 does not set the content-type Is this Intended or Have i to do Voodoo stuff for making it work ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - How to make $.post() use contentType=application/json?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845459/jquery-how-to-make-post-use-contenttype-application-json)

Comment: Code 2's `$.get` could be rewritten as `$.get(url)` since you aren't passing data or a callback function, and json is the default dataType due to the ajaxSetup.

Comment: @Starx lol this is a `Get` request, not a post. Post does work very well

Comment: @KevinB does Content-Type and dataType mean the same here ? if yes then what you say is correct. but i think content-Type specifies the mime-type of data expected from the request

Comment: @Deeptechtons Correct, but specifing "json" in $.get is pointless if you have already defined it as the default in ajaxSetup. Keep the ajaxSetup as it is, and use the shortened `$.get()`, the result should be the same. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @KevinB jquery  v1.7.1, but i would like to tell that it is indeed not setting the content type when requesting. let me add the images for reference

Comment: That's not related to the parameters passed in to `$.get`, `$.get()` does not accept a parameter to set the contentType, that should be handled by `$.ajaxSetup`. I'll hit the core right quick and see what's up.

Comment: I do see that happening, but it isn't related to $.get(). Try `$.ajax(url)` in it's place, you'll get the same result. If there is a bug, it's that `$.ajax()` doesn't look at `$.ajaxSetup` for the `contentType` parameter, but i haven't confirmed that yet.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but why does your `contentType` need to be `application/json` for your request headers when you aren't sending json with your request data?

Comment: @KevinB Because for a asp.net service method it requires the `content-type` to be set to `application/json` to be invoked correctly more on this here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx (see ASP.NET AJAX Content-Type Header Validation section) and here http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/

Comment: I would just create a wrapper method that uses $.ajax() with your own predetermined properties.

Comment: @KevinB I would mark your Idea as answer If you could put up any jQuery wrapper code and explain how(I do now understand how it is done)but for the sake of completion and a answer for future `Google Searches` a answer detailing would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just create a quick wrapper for the ajax method.

```
$.myAjax = function(url,data){
    return $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: url,
        data: data || {},
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
// used with
$.myAjax("foobar.asp").done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(){
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

The reason that the header isn't getting passed is that if the contentType isn't specified for the given request and there is no data, the contentType is not set. It may be a bug since the contentType was set in the ajaxSetup, but I'm not positive on that.

Comment: accepted as answer, I really wanted to appreciate your perseverance and dedication towards answering questions

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajaxSetup` hold the default options for most of the all ajax request, but **does not** send an ajax request it self.

But `$.ajax` is the actual function that sends the request.

---

On **Code 1**:

It simply sends a GET Ajax request with comprehensive method `$.ajax()`

On **Code 2**:

The default options for all the ajax request are set before any request are sent. Then when the actual request is made using $.get, this parameters no longer have to be defined.

---

**Update**

This seems to be a bug. Such problem occurs when you are sending `$.get` request without any data. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fzgjw/1/). You need to see the request headers using firebug or similar.

Comment: However, his `$.get()` does send the ajax request using the defaults set previously.

Comment: @Starx that i knew and i also mentioned title is misleading. read the problem defined below after code#2 code refuses to set Content-Type even though it is specified in ajaxsetup

Comment: @Deeptechtons, You are the asker how can you say your question's title is misleading and still not fix it.

Comment: @Starx jQuery does not set the Content-Type to application/json during get request that is the problem here, could be kind as to explain the reason for this

Comment: @Starx the title and the question has been changed, please look into it

Comment: @Deeptechtons, This seems to be bug, But I found a workaround. Check update

Comment: @Starx What happens at the fiddle that shows a bug? the request headers look correct. If there is a bug, it should be present in `$.ajax` too since `$.get` proxies directly to `$.ajax`

Comment: @KevinB, I dont get your question? Can you show a demo of your query?

Comment: Sorry, i see what you are seeing now.See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fzgjw/4/ it isn't just $.get, it's all ajax requests. We need to inspect what `$.ajaxSetup({},settings)` is doing.

Comment: Here's more testing, showing that the internal use of $.ajaxSetup is working properly, so moving past that. http://jsfiddle.net/fzgjw/6/

Comment: I found it, on line 7517, if no data is being sent, a contentType is not set. Again, this is not restricted to `$.get()`

Comment: @KevinB, Thats a admirable effort from your side. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Thats 7517 of 1.7.1, of course. However, how does this help the question? Code1 isn't sending data.

Comment: Of this conditional, `s.data && s.hasContent && s.contentType !== false || options.contentType` the only part that is in question in my opinion is `s.hasContent`, the rest are pretty obvious as being true in this case.