# jQuery POST request from inside an iFrame times out

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, iframe, bookmarklet

I have an iframe that is injected into an arbitrary webpage by a bookmarklet. It points to `http://localhost:5000/test`, which is a simple HTML page that runs the following Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:5000/parse",
  data: {data:"hello world"}
}).done(function( msg ) {
  console.log("Success!!", arguments);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log("Error", arguments);
});
```

I can see in the web inspector that the call is made, but it sits as *(pending)* until the request times out 30 seconds later. The server logs show that the server isn't being hit at all. The odd thing is that if I remove the *data* parameter in the ajax request, the server gets hit and things work as expected.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:5000/parse"
}).done(function( msg ) {
  console.log("Success!!", arguments); // this works.
});
```

I wouldn't expect cross-domain policy issues to be an issue since the iframe and the ajax request target are on the same domain. What am I missing here? Is there something at the browser level that is preventing this request from going through?

Answer (score 0):

try adding dataType and contentType, to the ajax settings

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:5000/parse",
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {data:"hello world"}
 }).done(function( msg ) {
     console.log("Success!!", arguments);
 }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log("Error", arguments);
 });
```

Comment: While its probably a good idea for me to add these (and I now have), it didn't solve the issue. The request still sits pending until it times out.

Comment: you may need to stringify the data, data: JSON.stringify({data:"test"}), suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845459/jquery-how-to-make-post-use-contenttype-application-json

Comment: Serializing the object with JSON.stringify unfortunately had no effect.