# Should data be encoded when sent via jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following script works (at least on the browser I am using).  That being said, is it best practice to encode the data before sending.  If so, how? Or is jQuery doing it automatically?

```
var address='1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC';
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    data: {
        address: address,
        sensor: false
    },
    success: function(json){console.log(json)}
});
```

Comment: jQuery encodes things properly already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > That being said, is it best practice to encode the data before sending. If so, how?

see [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2845459/851370) of JSON.stringify(data)
on [[Jquery - How to make $.post() use contentType=application/json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845459/jquery-how-to-make-post-use-contenttype-application-json])