# how to configure the http head in jQuery post function with spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have create a page and submit a post request to server, the jquery code like this

jquery code：

```
$("#button").click(function() {

    var book = {
        name: "book123",
        isbn: "123456"
    };

    $.post("book/add", book, function(data) {
        console.debug(data);
    });

});
```

Spring controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addBook(
        @RequestBody Book book, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    book.setRanking(DEFAULT_RANKING);
    Book returnbook = bookService.createBook(book);

    return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(returnbook);
}
```

But it has error, in firebug, I get this error code:

> NetworkError: 415 Unsupported Media Type - /book/add

the requst header information is this:

> Accept    */* Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Language   en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5
>
> Content-Length    24
>
> **Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8**
>
> DNT   1
>
> User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/24.0
>
> X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest

I think the content-type is not correct as in bold. How to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's  ajax function instead of post, where you can specify the type. 
To see how to use it, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019855/2504224) SO post
Also it would be good to set the `consumes` variable on @RequestMapping to "application/json"