# $.post(...) not recognizing JSON body

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to do a `POST` request to the server like this:

```
var body = {
    PatientAgeFilter: {
        CompareOperator: parseInt(self.patientAge()),
        MoreThanVal: {
            AgeSpecifier: 0,
            AgeValue: parseInt(self.patientAgeLow())
        },
        LessThanVal: {
            AgeSpecifier: 0,
            AgeValue: parseInt(self.patientAgeHigh())
        }
    }
};

$.post(url, body, self.results, "json").done(function () {
    console.log("request done!");
    console.log(self.results());
});
```

The URL is set correctly, `self.results` is a **Knockout.JS** `observableArray()`, and the body is set as above.

Server side, this is the code handling the request:

```
[HttpPost]
public IQueryable<Measurement> GetMeasurements(MeasurementQuery queryOptions)
{
    ...
    if (queryOptions != null) {
        if (queryOptions.PatientAgeFilter.CompareOperator != CompareOperator.Any) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I've set a breakpoint on `if (queryOptions != null)`, and queryOptions is not null. But the content of `queryOptions` stays default, even though I specify the fields in `body` (f.e. the `CompareOperator` should equal 3, but it stays 0 - which equals `CompareOperator.Any`), so the body of the `POST` request isn't parsed properly.

Can anybody help me out here as to why this happens? Much appreciated!

Comment: `self.results()` treated as a `method` call

Comment: Maybe you just need to stringify your results - JSON.stringify(self.results())

Comment: @hindmost That's not a problem, I've used that in other requests before without any errors or whatever.

Comment: @BobMac The results appear as they should, they're just not the results I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your `post` method is incorrect in 2 ways:
<del>1. As already stated in comments, you should use `JSON.stringify` for your data.</del>(see update below)
2. Third parameter (if present) must be a [success callback](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

So, this variant should work:

```
...
$.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), function(results) {
    self.results(results);
}, "json");
```

#### UPDATE 1:

The problem is not in `JSON.stringify` indeed, since WEB Api by default supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is default content-type for `$post()`. So, my next guess that the problem is with your server model. Make sure that `CompareOperator`, `MoreThanVal` and `LessThanVal` are actually properties, not fields (and all their children, which you would like to bind). WEB API doesn't bind fields.

Comment: The problem is not the callback function, but passing the body. If I look at the content of `body` when the request hits the breakpoint, the values are not properly filled in.

Comment: See my answer to the question - the problem was caused by the request body, as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was - as I thought - that the request body didn't get through to the server properly. I changed this

```
$.post(url, body, self.results, "json");
```

to the following

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:"POST",
    data:JSON.stringify(body), //necessary for the data to be parsed properly
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8", //important!
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(results){
        self.results(results);
    }
});
```

And now it works as it should.

I used **[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2845487/2286419)** for the answer.

Comment: Glad that helped. Although it's strange, that my updated answer didn't work out - I've checked it on my machine, works perfectly.

Comment: I know, I'd expect it to work too. Anyhow, I'm just glad I got this solved, been looking for more than a day for this issue.