# How to add another dataType in short-hand AJAX in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to add another new dataTypes in AJAX using short-hand method POST in jquery? Maybe someone who's expert in jquery can help me.

This is my AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
   url: myUrl,
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
   }
});
```

I want to convert it to short-hand;

```
$.post(myURL,{
                    formData
}).done(function(response){
    console.log(response)
}, contentType: false, processData: false, cache: false
);
```

But the above code is not working.

Comment: $.post will not do this.see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845459/jquery-how-to-make-post-use-contenttype-application-json post it may help.

Comment: What's the point of using a short-hand method if you still want to specify all the same arguments? If you just want to replace `success` with `.done()` that will work with `$.ajax()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn my point is how to add these `contentType: false, processData: false, cache: false` via short-hand method.

Comment: @aldrin27 Will settings change between `$.ajax()` calls ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes. But Suchit's comment give's me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may create your own function and define any logics there:

```
$.superCustomAjax = function(settings) {
    settings.contentType = settings.contentType || false;
    settings.cache = settings.cache || false;
    settings.processData = settings.processData || false;

    return jQuery.ajax(settings);
});

$.superCustomAjax({
    url: "./url.php",
    data: data,
    cache: true // overwrite default "false" value
});
```

Or more `$.post`-style like this:

```
$.superCustomAjax = function(url, data, settings) {
    settings.url = url;
    settings.data = data;

    settings.type = settings.type || "POST";
    settings.contentType = settings.contentType || false;
    settings.cache = settings.cache || false;
    settings.processData = settings.processData || false;

    return jQuery.ajax(settings);
});

$.superCustomAjax("./url.php", data, {
    cache: true // overwrite default "false" value
});
```

In both examples, `cache` value will be overwritten to `true`. However, `contentType` and `processData` will be `false` according to your custom defaults.