# WebApi Not Deserializing Correctly

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I'm at my wit's end here. I think I just need another set of eyes.

Method Signature:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(ApiRequest request)
```

Model:

```
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "CollectionNeverUpdated.Global")]
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "AutoPropertyCanBeMadeGetOnly.Global")]
public class ApiRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("allowLoadingToDataWarehouse")]
    public bool AllowLoadingToDataWarehouse { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("initialDelay")]
    public string InitialDelay { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("reportIds")]
    public IEnumerable<string> ReportIds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reportTypeDelay")]
    public string ReportTypeDelay { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("runType")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ReportRunType RunType { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("userId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("wwDelay")]
    public string WWDelay { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("weeks")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Weeks { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript:

```
   var submitReportRequest = {
        userId: userid,
        reportIds: reportids,
        runType: 'Custom',
        weeks: selectedweeks,
        initialDelay: $('#InitialDelay').val(),
        reportTypeDelay: $('#ReportTypeDelay').val(),
        wwDelay: $('#WWDelay').val(),
        allowLoadingToDataWarehouse: $('#AllowLoadingToDataWarehouse').val()
   };

   $.post("/api/SubmitReport", JSON.stringify(submitReportRequest), function (data) {
        alert('success');
   });
```

Serialized Json From JavaScript Post:

```
{
  "userId": "30",
  "reportIds": [
    "59",
    "60",
    "61",
    "62",
    "63",
    "64"
  ],
  "runType": "Custom",
  "weeks": [
    "201409",
    "201410",
    "201411",
    "201412"
  ],
  "initialDelay": "00:00:00",
  "reportTypeDelay": "00:00:00",
  "wwDelay": "00:00:00"
}
```

Quickwatch of Deserialized Object
[image: Quickwatch of Deserialized Object]

Initially I had `int` and `TimeSpan` for the Ids and Delays, respectively, and those were not deserializing correctly. So I changed them all to strings, and they're still not deserializing correctly.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Edit: After trying every combination of attributes, I finally decided to stick it into the Fiddler Composer. And it works. So something must be off with my JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by "not deserializing correctly?" What behavior are you observing?

Comment: Try to remove all custom `JsonProperty` attributes, and eventually try to use `[FromBody] ApiRequest request` in the API signature. Just to understand what is going on...

Comment: Also, while I cannot say for sure it's causing your problem, there's no reason ReportIds can't be an ICollection or IList since you're deserializing it off of a Javascript array anyway, so there's no lazy iteration going on.

Comment: @NickBailey I originally tried a `List` but that wasn't working either. I'll try some other Collections.

Comment: @KennethK. None of my values are being deserialized. I'm getting nulls or default values. See the `QuickWatch of Deserialized Object` image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that shorthand JQuery `post()` method was setting the `Content-Type` attribute on the Request to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` when it needed to be set to `application/json; charset=UTF-8`

I found by watching the Network traffic in Chrome, and by changing my javascript to this
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019855/2607840).