# jQuery $.post(url, json, promise, "json") has bad request while $.ajax() doesn't. Don't know why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

In jQuery, I am referencing https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
. But I think I have problems with jQuery's $.post() when I follow their template very closely, i.e.,

```
  $.post( "test.php", { func: "getNameAndTime" }, function( data ) {
     console.log( data.name ); // John
     console.log( data.time ); // 2pm
  }, "json");
```

Here's my code:

```
$( document ).ready(
function ()    {
    var javaObj = {
        _dataFreq: "0"
        , _period: $( "#interval" ).val()
        , _time: $( "#dayTo" ).val() + ".00"
        , _ptNames: $( "#ptNames" ).val().split( ',' ) //string[]
    }
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST'
        , url: mySrvEndPont
        , data: JSON.stringify(javaObj) 
        , success: function ( response ) {
            alert( "OK");
        }
        , error: function ( e ) {
            alert( e );
        }
        , contentType: "application/json"
        , dataType: "json"
    } );
    $.post( mySrvEndPont, JSON.stringify(javaObj), function ( response )
    {
            alert( "OK" );
    } , "json")
    ;
} );
```

I got "OK" and a valid response object from $.ajax(), but nothing except a 400 bad request from $.post() !!!  Just want to know why.

Comment: A good way to trace the mistake is check and compare both requests (compare headers, parameters) sent to your server. Did you try it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845459/jquery-how-to-make-post-use-contenttype-application-json

Comment: It would help if your code wasnt formatted all funky

Comment: Try this link to find the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845459/jquery-how-to-make-post-use-contenttype-application-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Compare Headers]

The difference is one header ($.ajax's) having Content-Type = application/json set correct while the other has application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 (wrong!). I guess that kills it.  Unless jQuery has a 'complete' documentation on how to set the content-type to application/json in their shorthand $.post(), I will resort to using $.ajax() !!!

Comment: If this answer (or another) provided you with a resolution you should accept that by clicking the check to the left. If not, please update your question as to why not OR add a new answer that did.

Answer (score 1):

I think that **$.post** does not set the content type header as `"application/json"`, and that could probably be the cause of the bad request status.

If i'm right, you should not use the **$.post** shorthand, go with **$.ajax** and set the content type manually.

This:

```
$.post(mySrvEndPont, JSON.stringify(javaObj), function(d){} , "json");
```

is a shorthand for this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    url: mySrvEndPont,
    data: JSON.stringify(javaObj),
    success: function (d) {},
    dataType: "json"
});
```

And if i'm supposing right, what you actually need is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    url: mySrvEndPont,
    data: JSON.stringify(javaObj),
    success: function (d) {},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: That still doesn't set the content type. The last argument specifies the type of the response, not the type of the content.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that is exactly what i've tried to say. Maybe i didn't phrase it correctly (not a native english speaker). Sorry for that.

Comment: I thought you were showing the correct way to write it to set the content type. If not, how does this solve the problem?

Comment: Just edited, hope it's more clear now. If the content type is the actual problem, the solution would be not using the $.post function.

Comment: Nice! That 'json' is setting the type/format of the response that you got from the server, the contentType sets the http header **content type** instead, which indicates the format of the data you're sending to the server. It seems that google validates that before parsing your request.

Comment: Leonardo is perfectly correct! That little param "json" at the end of the $.post () did not set the posted data to content-type json! Who knows what that little "json" is doing? But it is answered by Leonardo :) !