# Edit returned data and send edited data back using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to edit returned data from AJAX, and then return back that edited data using AJAX.

The first AJAX request succeeds but the second doesn't. I can't find out what is wrong. Any help please?

```js
  function first_func() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "get_updated_data.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        original_data
      },
    })
  }

  function second_func(secondData) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "get_updated_data.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        edited_data
      },
    })
  }

  first_func().then(function(data) {
    var NewData = data;

    function editReturnedData() {
      // edit first returned data here
    }
    return result;
  }
  second_func(secondData);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you embedded data to send (`edited_data`) **into curly braces** ?

In your `first_func` POST you are sending data as JSON. But not in your `second_func` POST. **What format is accepted** by your endpoint `get_updated_data.php` ?

### jQuery POST form-data (traditional)

Using POST method the *default* **contentType** is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`. So if not specified other *contentType* you usually have two options:

1. **query-string**
2. **object** (key-value) *which gets transformed to query-string by jQuery internally before sending*

See docs [jQuery ajax, Section "Sending Data to the Server"](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings):

> The data option can contain either a **query string** of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`, or an **object** of the form `{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}`. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This processing can be circumvented by setting processData to false. The processing might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to the server; in this case, change the contentType option from application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.

According to this you should call jQuery's `ajax` function as follows:

```
var  edited_data = "name=ravi&age=31";  // query string
//    or
var edited_data = {name:"ravi",age:"31"}; // object (key-value pairs) 

$.ajax({
    url : "get_updated_data.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : edited_data,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

### jQuery POST data as JSON

You would like to send data as JSON and your PHP-endpoint expects so. 
Your post-settings need these adjustments:

- `dataType: 'JSON'` (from your *first_func*)
- `data: JSON.stringify(data)` (from your *second_func*)
- `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Then best-approach is to wrap that into a function like following:

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
  return jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: url,
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',  // header used by endpoint
     data: JSON.stringify(data), // needed since JSON is sent in body as string
     dataType: 'json', // this tells jQuery how to handle data-response
     success: callback // this will be your callback-function
  });
};
```

### See also

- for simple HTML-form POSTing: [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)
- for sending JSON: [Jquery - How to make $.post() use contentType=application/json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845459/jquery-how-to-make-post-use-contenttype-application-json)

Comment: I'm writing `var original_data = JSON.stringify( data );` before my code to make it object, not sure if that's the best way, I'll check that doc later, thank you!

Comment: @Kiki Thanks for that info. No, `JSON.stringify` is most-likely wrong as well as embedding `original_data` into curly-braces. So you will effectively send a **string** like `'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'`. But your PHP-endpoint doesn't want to receive a __string__, right?

Comment: I want to send and receive data in json...is that also the reason for that second function is not working properly?

Comment: Yes.. then we have to include the good parts of both your func's. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Thank you @hc_dev!, I thought the problem was in `first_func().then(function(data)....`. I couldn't think about there was a problem about the way I was sending data! You saved my day!