# Jquery JQGrid breaks when contentType=application/json?

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, content-type

I've had to use $.ajaxSetup() to globally change the contentType to application/json

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

(See this question for why I had to use application/json [ASPNET MVC - Why is ModelState.IsValid false "The x field is required" when that field does have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792603/aspnet-mvc-why-is-modelstate-isvalid-false-the-x-field-is-required-when-that))

But this breaks the jquery jqrid with this error:

```
Invalid JSON primitive: _search
```

The POST data it is trying to send is:

```
_search=false&nd=1274042681880&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
```

Which of is not in json format, so of course it fails.  Is there anyway to tell jqrid what contenttype to use?

I have searched on the jqrid wiki, but doesn't have much documentation about anything really.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?do=search&id=contenttype&fulltext=Search

Comment: The solution I'm likely to use is to not have the $.ajaxSetup, and convert any $.post() that must be application/json to a $.ajax() call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I can forward you the my old answer [Setting the content-type of requests performed by jQuery jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731). It shows how the ajax request looks like inside of jqGrid. So you should use `ajaxGridOptions` parameter of jqGrid instead of overwriting global settings with respect of `$.ajaxSetup`.

Moreover in the same answer you can see how you `serializeGridData` parameter of jqGrid can be used to make your custom serialization. In [How do I build a JSON object to send to an AJAX WebService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737525/how-do-i-build-a-json-object-to-send-to-an-ajax-webservice/2738086#2738086) you can read how should JSON encoding of parameters look like.

If you will stay have problem with using `serializeGridData` and `ajaxGridOptions` you should include in your question the code fragment of using jqGrid and the prototype of your server's method of the web service which you use.

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting up jqGrid or it's datasource, set it's [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to JSON (`"json"`), like this:

```
$("#myTable").jqGrid ({
  //other options...
  dataType : 'json'
});
```

[You can see an example on code project as well](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/jqGrid.aspx).

Comment: small remark: to receive `dataType : 'json'` in the corresponding jQuery.ajax request one should use `datatype : 'json'` as parameter of jqGrid (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options).